# Grouping with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I get information of sales from different shops per day. My first attempt was to use:

```
SELECT DATE(TimeStamp) as DATE,SUM(Sales) FROM gain Group by DATE(TimeStamp)
```

what works fine.

Now I need to know the results of each shop within that day. I need to get the `shop_name` somewhere in.

The next is to show only the last 7 days (`INTERVAL 7 DAY`), but how and where?

Comment: Share your table schema structure and sample data.

Comment: And desired result

Answer (score 1):

If shop_name column is in gain table , query will be like below.

```
SELECT DATE(TimeStamp) as DATE,
SUM(Sales) as total_sales, shop_name
FROM gain 
WHERE DATE(TimeStamp) >=  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
GROUP BY DATE, shop_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query make `INTERVAL 7 DAY` & if you want to select `shop_name` somewhere in the `table` you need to [JOIN](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) with this table.

```
SELECT DATE(TimeStamp) as DATE,
SUM(Sales) as total_sales
FROM gain 
WHERE DATE(TimeStamp) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(TimeStamp)
```